# Select com o último registro

Tags: sql, select

Preciso valorizar o inventário da empresa em que trabalho e para isso vou pegar o último valor dos itens. Estava usando o `MAX`, mas percebi que se fizesse isso, ele iria me retornar o maior preço e não o último cadastrado na tabela. Então mudei o `MAX` pra coluna de data, só que ele me traz várias linhas de resultados, e preciso apenas da última mas ainda com o campo de código e valor para depois jogar em uma planilha.

**Código:**

```
SELECT irec.pro_in_codigo Codigo,
       irec.rci_re_vlunitario Valor_unitario,
       max(irec.rcb_dt_documento) Data    
FROM mgadm.est_itensreceb irec    
WHERE irec.pro_in_codigo = 701    
GROUP BY irec.pro_in_codigo, irec.rci_re_vlunitario
```

Comment: Você quer obter o último registro da tabela?

Answer (score 1):

Veja se assim funciona:

```
select irec.pro_in_codigo Codigo,
       irec.rci_re_vlunitario Valor_unitario,
       irec.rcb_dt_documento Data
from mgadm.est_itensreceb irec
where irec.pro_in_codigo = 701 
    and irec.rcb_dt_documento = (select max(irec.rcb_dt_documento) Data
            from mgadm.est_itensreceb irec
            where irec.pro_in_codigo = 701
            )
```

Comment: Provavelmente seu código não irá funcionar já que o `alias` `irec` está sendo utilizado para mais de uma tabela

Comment: @Sorack, com oracle funciona, já fiz esse teste algumas vezes, agora não sei em outros SGBD's.

Answer (score 0):

Faça o select conforme exemplo abaixo.

```
SELECT IREC.PRO_IN_CODIGO CODIGO,
   IREC.RCI_RE_VLUNITARIO VALOR_UNITARIO,
   IREC.RCB_DT_DOCUMENTO
FROM MGADM.EST_ITENSRECEB IREC
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT IREC.PRO_IN_CODIGO, /* CAMPOS CHAVES DA TABELA */
                MAX(IREC.RCB_DT_DOCUMENTO) AS MAXDT
            FROM  MGADM.EST_ITENSRECEB IREC
            GROUP BY  IREC.PRO_IN_CODIGO
       ) TV_MAX ON (TV_MAX.PRO_IN_CODIGO = IREC.PRO_IN_CODIGO AND IREC.RCB_DT_DOCUMENTO = TV_MAX.MAXDT)
WHERE IREC.PRO_IN_CODIGO = 701
```

Answer (score 0):

No firebird faço assim:

```
SELECT   FIRST 1
         VALOR_UNITARIO
FROM     ESTOQUE
WHERE    CODIGO = :CODIGO
ORDER BY DATA DESC
```